# Redirecting old HTTPS site with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've searched quite thoroughly and can't find an answer to this...

So basically I have a website set up, www.supersaturated.co.uk all working great with https and the relevant htaccess redirects.

The client has an old website which was secure, www.supersaturated.net. This is now a parked domain on a new hosting account.

The problem I'm having is that the SSL certificate on the new site is only for that .co.uk domain. If someone goes to http://www.supersaturated.net it redirects to the secure .co.uk as it should. But if someone goes to https://www.supersaturated.net it gives the browser warning for an untrusted connection. Is there a way to redirect this or is the browser just seeing the lack of SSL for the .net before even attempting a redirect?

Here is the relevant part of my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.supersaturated\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.supersaturated.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that browser is seeing the lack of SSL for the `.net` before even attempting a redirect rule. This is due to the fact that cert negotiation between web server and browser happens before `mod_rewrite` is invoked (due to security reasons).

Comment: How will adding javascript to the head of the page help if I get the warning before the page loads?